# What are the possible values for n if there is an injective homomorphism from $Z_{n}$ to $S_{7}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-homomorphism

I am guessing that $Z_{7}$ is the only $Z_{n}$ who can have injective homomorphism to $S_{7}$ by Cayley theorem. My mapping is for any $x\in Z$, $f(x) = \begin{bmatrix}x+0&x+1 &x+ 2 &x +3 &x+4 &x+5 &x+6\\ 0&1 &2 &3 &4 &5 &6\end{bmatrix} $. This mapping is isomorphism so it should be injective homomorphism too.

However I have no idea how to argue that this is the only $Z$ group injective homomorphism.

Or is there any other $Z_{n}$ which is injective homomorphism to $S_{7}$?

Comment: Well, $\Bbb Z_2$ and $\Bbb Z_3$ inject into $S_3$, which certainly injects into $S_7$.

Comment: and what about $\Bbb Z_1?$

Comment: There are some more than $n = 7$ that work.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Since $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic and you want to define an isomorphism onto the image, you need to figure out which cyclic subgroups $S_7$ has.

Edit: No, not only $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$ can be embedded into $S_7$. There will be $9$ different $n$ that work.

Comment: Thank you for your and. Does 9 different n mean [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,12] ?

Comment: Yes. Exactly these $9$. Good job!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** There is an injective homomorphism from $\mathbb Z_n$ into $S_7$ if and only if there is an element $g\in S_7$ whose order is $n$; just consider the map from $\mathbb Z_n$ into $S_n$ defined by $k\mapsto g^k$. So, what are the possible orders of element of $S_7$?